# Implement structured temporal random effects to account for repetitive measurements within days in Hmsc

Tags: r

Despite following the code and answers to similar questions – but I still struggle in how to specify a structured temporal random effects in a data set without spatial information.

E.g the code provided here https://gitlab.com/dfo-msea/groundfish-multispecies-model/-/blob/master/code/2_fit_model.R?ref_type=heads (appendix of a published paper).

I have been monitoring bumblebee communities in 2 forest plots, for 7 days, from sunrise to sunset (so 16 time points/day – with sunrise/sunset being monitored only in one of the two plots each day, but all of the other time points were sampled for both plots).

I am aiming at defining 3 random effects In the Hmsc model:

- A random effect at the plot level
- A structured random effect of time nested within date – to model the fact that within an observational day, what was observed hour after hour was related to the community observed earlier in the day.

Here is the data structure

```
head(XData)
date  plot time flowers    av.li    av.tp duration
1 220512  open    0     8.4 4.615006 6.861538       60
2 220512  open    1     8.4 6.973745 7.333333       15
3 220512 dense    1     6.6 7.387100 7.666667       15
4 220512  open    2     8.4 7.819142 7.975000       15
5 220512 dense    2     6.6 8.082691 8.040000       15
6 220512  open    3     8.4 8.854704 9.040000       15


#Definition of the study design matrix -

studyDesign <- matrix(NA, nrow(data), 3)
studyDesign <- as.data.frame(studyDesign)
studyDesign[,1] <- XData$plot
studyDesign[,1]<-as.factor(studyDesign[,1])
studyDesign[,2] <- paste('time', XData$time, sep = "_")
studyDesign[,2]<-as.factor(studyDesign[,2])
studyDesign[,3] <- paste('date', XData$date, sep = "_")
studyDesign[,3]<-as.factor(studyDesign[,3])
colnames(studyDesign) <- c("plot", "time", "date")

head(studyDesign)
   plot   time        date
1  open time_0 date_220512
2  open time_1 date_220512
3 dense time_1 date_220512
4  open time_2 date_220512
5 dense time_2 date_220512
6  open time_3 date_220512
```

NB: I have done similar analysis with the time and date defined respectively as factors from 0 (sunrise) to 17 (sunset) and the format 220512 (For 12 May 2022).

```
#TIME
time <- unique(studyDesign[,2])
xy <- as.data.frame(XData %>% dplyr::select(time))
xy <- unique(xy)
colnames(xy) <- c("time")
sRL <- xy
rownames(sRL) <- time
rL_T <- HmscRandomLevel(sData = sRL)

#PLOT AND DATE
rL2 = HmscRandomLevel(units = unique(studyDesign$plot))
rL3= HmscRandomLevel(units = unique(studyDesign$date))

#DEFINITION OF THE MODEL
m.r = Hmsc(Y = Y1,
XData = XData, XFormula = XFormula,
TrData = TrData, TrFormula = TrFormula,
distr = "probit",
ranLevels  = list("plot"=rL2, "date"=rL3,"time"=rL_T ),
studyDesign = studyDesign)`
```

The model is running, but I don’t manage to understand if I have managed to properly specify the temporal structure of the repetitive sampling – with the 17 hours of monitoring within each of the 7 days – most of all that when I read the specifications of the temporal random effect I am fearing that the model is considering the times in a wrong order (e.g. 1, 11, 12, 13 […], 17, 2, 3, 4 […] 9” instead of 0, 1,2 […] 17). I have tried to order the factor manually within the studyDesign dataframe but it provided the same results.

Would anyone have advice on how to properly specify these random effects to have a structured temporal random effect nested within the date – while keeping the right time order?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance,

Océane